# System health issue in Confluent control center

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-control-center

We are using confluent kafka control center but out system health page doesnt work and always shows try again.

I went through doc and verified theh settings are same but still facing the issue.

The error it throws is
Unable to check ulimit: cannot run program ulimit error=2 no such file or directory (io.confluent.controlcenter.healthcheck.HealthCheck)

Apart from above i see below logs

- problem getting connectors
- failed to connect to kafka-connect javax. ws.rs.ProcessingException
- failed to submit metrics to confluent to secure and insecure both.
- misconfigured topic = _confluent-metrics config =min.insync.replicas value =2 expected =1

Comment: `ulimit: cannot run program ulimit error=2` is not an error, it's just a warning that you can ignore. Can you provide more details - version, how are you deploying it, what errors are there in the Confluent Control Center logs, etc?

Comment: The version is working in our qa env with same config and the issue is only with system health page, the consumer lag page works fine

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: Confluent 5.0.1.2 apache kafka  2.1 it uses i think

Comment: Are there errors are there in the Confluent Control Center logs, or the browser console?

Comment: Only error is cannot submit metric otherwise most of the logs are similar to qa

Comment: That metrics topic is important for the system health page. But you also need to look at the logs of the brokers to ensure the metrics reporters are working

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved, there was some problem with compact, delete policy since there are no keys it has to be delete only